# Lines after Glareing Object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am currently creating a character and i have a problem. I added a Glare Node (Whith a add Node) on my Project and now i have these lines and this white strip on my sword. How can i fix that? [image: Lines on my Object]

[image: Glare node]

[image: Add Node]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of your node setup in the compositor? That would help troubleshooting

Comment: I solved the problem for the Sword. I now have only the problem with the eyes.